# How to take snapshot of Aws EBS volumes using Ruby skd v2?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and trying to learn. I am trying to take snapshot of EBS volume using `Ruby aws-sdk v2`. I found command for taking snapshots using `CLI` and using `aws-sdk v1`. But I am not able to find much information about taking snapshot using `aws-sdk v2`.

This is how I am trying to take snapshot.

`ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region: config['region'], credentials: credentials)`

(note i have other methods to read config file and load credentials)

Then I am trying to take snapshot

`ec2.snapshots.create(:volume => ec2.volumes[volume_id], :description => "Snapshot of device: #{device_name} volume: #{volume_id}")`

(note i have saved `device_name` and `volume_id` in hash, this is just a snippet of code). I am getting error for `ec2.volumes[volume_id]` saying `undefined method 'volumes' for #<Aws::EC2::Client>`.

I think this method is for `aws-sdk v1`. Do we have similar method for `aws-sdk v2`? Please guide me to right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a snapshot two ways using version 2 of the AWS SDK for Ruby. Using the resources interface (this will be the most like v1):

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new
ec2.volume('volume-id').create_snapshot(description: 'description')
```

Or you can use the client class:

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new
ec2.create_snapshot(volume_id: 'volume-id', description: 'description')
```

Please note, the v2 SDK is not backwards compatible, so a few of the patterns from v1 have changed.

Comment: so what do i need to put in place of `snapshot-id`? I am guessing it will be `volume-id` ??

Comment: Ooops. That was a typo. I've corrected the example now. That should have been `volume_id`, not `snapshot_id`. Sorry about that.